# determine that $P(Y-X<0.28) = 0.7881$. Calculate $i$.

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

Last year, the daily price of corn per bushel,X, was normally distributed with a mean of
$5$ and a standard deviation of $0.75$. This year, assume the daily price of corn bushel, Y ,
has the same distribution as last year, but is i% greater than the last year due inflation.
An analysis determined that $P(Y -X < 0.28) = 0.7881$. Calculate $i$.

This is what I have:

$Y-X\sim N(5i-5,.75^2+(.75i^2))$

CLT:

$P\bigg(\frac{ .28-(5i-5))}{\sqrt{.75^2+(.75i)^2}}<.28\bigg)=.7881$

Using Z score table $P(Z<Z_1)=.81$

$P\bigg(\frac{ .28-(5i-5))}{\sqrt{.75^2+(.75i)^2}}=.81\bigg)$

Solve for $i$

And I get $i=.83$ However the answer is 5% where did I go wrong?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding...why would the new mean be $5i-5$?

Comment: i assumed since $Y$ is i% more that the mean of $Y$ would be $5i$

Comment: Ah, you are talking about the distribution of the difference, as you clearly wrote.  My mistake.  But the problem is a bit confusing...What does $Y-X$ mean, physically? On any given day you can only sample one or the other.

Comment: But shouldn't the mean of $Y$ be  $(1+i)\times 5$?

Comment: how do we get $(1+i)\cdot 5$ as the new mean

Comment: Well, say $i=.05$, as in the official solution.  You are claiming, I think, that the mean of $Y$ would then be $i\times 5=.05\times 5=.25$ which makes no sense.  To increase by $i$ would mean the new mean should be $(1+.05)\times 5=5.25$

Comment: but if you didnt know the answer was 5% how would you get the mean to be that? because you stated $(1+i)\cdot 5$ but distribute that you get $5+5i$ but $X-Y$ im pretty sure means you subtract those two means

Comment: I just used $,05$ as an example.  Call it $i$ if you don't want to specify a value.  Inflation makes the mean go up.  The increase is given by $i$.  So the new mean is bigger than the old mean by $i$ times the old mean.  That is, $\mu (Y-X)=5i$.

Comment: To be clear:  I don't see $i=.05$ as a possible answer.  If I have understood the problem (far from clear), the mean of $Y-X$ is $.25$ which is practically the same as $.28$ so the probability that $Y-X$ is $<.28$ should be very close to $.5$

Comment: Oh, I think I understand the problem.  It is extremely poorly worded.  They just want you to solve for $i$ given that $\text {Prob}\left(X<\frac {.28}i\right)=.7881$  Very hard to follow the phrasing.

Comment: The trick is where they say that $Y,X$ have "the same distribution", which doesn't really make sense since they have different means and variances.  What they mean to say is "draw a random value of $X$.  Compute $Y$ by taking $(1+i)X$.  Then check whether the difference $Y-X=(1+i)X-X=iX<.28$ which is the same as drawing $X$ and asking if it is $<\frac {.28}i$.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $Y$ is $i\%$ greater than $X$ $\implies Y=X\left(1+\frac{i}{100}\right)\implies Y-X=\frac{i}{100}X$.

Therefore, $Y-X\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\frac{5i}{100},\left(\frac{0.75i}{100}\right)^2\right)$. Let $\Phi$ be the cdf of standard normal distribution. Then,

\begin{align}
P(Y−X<0.28)=0.7881 \implies &\Phi\left(\frac{0.28-\frac{5i}{100}}{\frac{0.75i}{100}}\right)=0.7881\\
\implies& \frac{0.28-0.05i}{0.075i}=0.7998\implies i = 5.0001\%.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing of the problem is, I think, extremely hard to follow.  Reverse engineering the official solution ($i=.05$) leads me to the following interpretation:

For any given $i$:  choose a value for $X$ from the given distribution.  Compute the probability that $(1+i)X-X=iX$ is less than $.28$  Solve for the value of $i$ that makes that probability $.7881$

For instance, had we guessed the value $i=.03$ we'd now want to find the probability that $X<\frac {.28}{.03}$.  As that comes to $X<9.\overline 3$ we see that the probability is effectively $1$, so $i=.03$ is not correct.  Indeed, numerically we can solve this problem to get $i=.05000103$ which, indeed, is effectively $.05$